# Icon element disturbing the flow of button on mouse hover event, how to I rearrange the icon on the button to make sure this doesn't happen?

Tags: html, css

[image]

When I hover on the "message" part of the button, the hover animation works, but when i hover over the icon, the hover animation doesn't happen and this makes it a poor button.

Here's the HTML

```
<div>
    <i className="profile-user-button-message-icon">message</i>
    <button className="button-icon-message ">Message</button>
</div>
```

Hope this information is enough to understand my problem, comment below if you need more information, thanks!

It's React code, hence the "className".

CSS Code for icon

```
.profile-user-button-message-icon{
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:20px;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k1h7rxmc/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write `button:before {content: ''; display: inline-block; width: 10px; height: 10px; background: url('your bg-image');}`

Comment: or use glyphicon, fontawesome for icon

Comment: for example div i{background: red;}
div:hover i{background: blue;}

Comment: I'm using material icons by Google.. Can't I use absolute positioning or something? Not setting the background image for the button. Just creating a span with the button class of material icons and placing it on the button

Comment: give me a fiddle

Comment: problem was in cursor?

Comment: Ahhhh! Thanks a lot :D
I didn't think of nesting it inside the button, you saved a lot of my time.

Comment: All ingenious is simple